# How to unbind an event that is bound by "on(function)"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edit: the best way i found now is using `$(this).off(event)` which could unbind your .on(function) just after you use it in some case

for example:

```
        $(body).on("click",function(event){
            //if user click outside #yourdiv then remove it and unbind the .on(function)
            if( ! $("#yourdiv").is(event.target)){
                $("#yourdiv").remove()
                //use off() to unbind this event
                $(this).off(event)
            }
        })
```

---

I want to bind a click event to `$("*")` to listen if the user clicks outside of a block, and then unbind this click event.

I have already tried:

```
$("*").on("click", function(event) {
    if (!$("#block").is(event.target)) {
        //do something
        $("*").off("click")
    }
})
```

But it works badly, because I made a lot of this type `on`(function) to `$("*")`, which creates a lot of interruptions and the whole system explodes.

I need to know how to unbind **"this"** function bound by the `on`(function), but don't do anything to other functions (even if they are all bound to the same target).

Or how can I listen to a click that happens outside the block (what I have tried is all copied from the 2012 answers maybe there's some smarter way?)

Thanks for any help!

---

edition:

i tried this made by Mark Baijens

```
$("#container").one("click",":not(.exclude, .exclude *)",(event)=>{
            event.stopPropagation();
            //do something
        })
```

but my structure is like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="block_1">
        <div class="exclude"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_2>
        <div class="not_exclude"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my new question is: i need to listen the click in container, and when it not drop down in the `<div class="exclude>` it goes function, and then unbind the function to avoid any interruption.

---

i solved this question finally. becaus of my silly structure, `.one()` is not so useful for me, the jq selector cant find what i really need. its such a pity because i like it, it looks really beautiful :(

i had only turn back to using `.off()` to unbind the function bind by `.on()`. and thanks to the comment by @Justinas after searching from a lot of text, i now know how to unbind the *event function*

```
        $("#container").on("click",function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            if(!$(".exclude").is(event.target)){
                //do something
                $(this).off(event)
            }
        })
```

it can perfectly work even i bind a lot `click` to `$("#container")`, im not very clear about the principle,but i think the

`event` in `$(this).off(event)`

is direct to the

`function` in `.on("click",function(event)`

and it would perfectly unbind the function bind by `.on()`

im not sure if it work in any situation, but at least now i had not found any bug

if someone in you guys could explain the principle of this, that would be greatly helpful to me

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).off('click')`?

Comment: You can separate out your function definition and mention it while removing event listener. `$("*").on("click", myFunc);` and  `$("*").off("click", myFunc);`

Comment: Binding a click event to all elements sounds horrible, why don't you use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) instead? Makes it easier to filter out an inner block too.

Comment: Just attach to the document or the parent container that you are looking for clicks in. Definitely don't use `"*"`

Comment: @CodeThing i tried this, but it does not work : ( $("*").on("click", myFunc(event,a)) and $("*").off("click", myFunc(event,a)), i dont know why but the "myFunc" will call  four times, and i dont want it happens, did i make any mistake? thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Many events in javascript (including the click event) propagate to their parents. Because you add a click event handler to every element all the parents execute the handler as well.  You could stop that with the `stopPropagation()` function, but way better in your case would be to do event delegation from the upper most parent as I and others recommended earlier.

Comment: @MarkBaijens i definitely agree with you, i will use $(document) instead of $("*") ! but sadly it does not helping the unbind nightmare :( . by the way, thanksfor your suggestion!

Comment: @MarkBaijens you are right! it does not making annoying recall !  i can try to use .off() to unbind it now !  thanks so much !

Comment: Do you only want to execute the handler once? You could then use the jQuery [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method instead of `on()`.

Comment: @MarkBaijens i tried this, but a horrible thing is when user click inside of the block, the listener will also shutdown, and i dont know how to make it still , i tried while(), but it turned the whole chorm shutdown X(

Comment: ` $("").on("click", myFunc)` *not* ` $("").on("click", myFunc(event,a))` - the second calls the function and passes the return of that function as the click handler.   You could also do: ` $("").on("click", (event) => myFunc(event,a))` if it helps you understand.

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. Please write what you are trying to solve instead of how you think your solution that does not work can be "fixed". Please click [edit] and then post a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: @freedomn-m this is what i need ! thank you so much for, i keeping using wrong way to call the function and now i know why, thanks again for your suggestiong, it so helpful to me !

Comment: @mplungjan im so sorry for such noob question ! but i just cant describe my problem currectly,  its  not my purpose to misunderstand guys,  apologize again for it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging on the comments I think you want this.

An event handler that is executed once when the user clicks anywhere except for some elements.

---

You could do that with the jQuery `one()` function on the wrapping element(s), this could be `document` for the whole page. In the example I put a wrapping element with the id `wrapper`.

You can then use the event delegation method with a css not selector to exclude some elements. In the example I excluded the elements with the class `exclude` and all their sub elements.

To make sure the function is really called only once and not multiple times due to propagation we need to stop the propagation too.

```js
$('#wrapper').one('click', ':not(.exclude, .exclude *)', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log("clicked valid target!");
});
```

```css
.exclude {
  background: red;
}https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77079597/how-to-unbind-an-event-that-is-bound-by-onfunction/77080131?noredirect=1#
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>Click</div>
  <div>Anywhere</div>
  <div>Once</div>
  <div class="exclude">But
    <div>not
      <div>here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>Here is fine</div>
  <div class="exclude">not here either</div>
  <input class="exclude" value="exclude this input">
  <input value="not this input">
  <div>But
    <div>here
      <div>is fine</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: such beautiful your codes are, this is completely what i want, not just this i now understand what causes my question and then im not made it happen again, my sincerest thanks for you my hero !

Comment: it so shame to asking for your help again， you see,  my "exclude" is not a div but a `<input class="exclude">`  and for some reason when i using `$("#container").one("click",":not(.exclude, .exclude *)",(event)=>{})` , it just not working to exclude the `:not(exclude)` thing，i go checked some text but got nothing ,  may you know what makes it happend ?

Comment: Please update your question with a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As you can see in my updated example it works for inputs as well. The stop propagation might be conflicting with other code you have. If that's the case you might need te remove the handler manually.

Comment: i go test it for a while and i found the question is coming from the `:not()`, it can only work in $("#container")'s first child, however my `<input class="exclude">` is in the third child,  so it does not work fine, would you have any suggestion for this poor situation? (if not needing me change the structure for best plz)